# Types of BarCodeURL

Tags: marketing-cloud, documentation

I have not found this in the documentation.
Is there a list of all codes supported for the function: BarCodeURL?

I have tried with a "Code39" and a "EAN13" code and both work just fine. But when I use "QRCode" the imagen display a gray square with the text "Live Content"

Example:

[image: QR Code Not Working]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to ExactTarget marketing cloud.

According to documentation:

> ...This function does not support matrix (2-D) barcodes such as QR codes.

http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/

Comment: Thanks I have missed that page... I was checking in the wrong place: [https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/content/BarCodeURL.html](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/content/BarCodeURL.html)